# Using MySQL, how do I select query result rank of one particular row?

Tags: php, mysql, rank

I've spent quite a lot of time today trying various things, but none of them seem to work. Here's my situation, I'd like to be able to select the rank of a row based on it's ID from a specifically sorted row

For example, if my query is something like:

```
SELECT id, name FROM people ORDER BY name ASC
```

with results like:

```
id   name
3    Andrew
1    Bob
5    Joe
4    John
2    Steve
```

I would like to get the rank (what row it ends up in the results) without returning all the rows and looping throw them until I get to the one I want (in PHP).

For example, I'd like to select the 'rank' of 'Steve' so that it returns -- in this case -- 5 (not his id, but the 'rank' of his name in the above query).

Similarly, I'd like to be able to select the rank of whatever row has the ID of 1. For this example, I'd like to return a 'rank' of 2 (because that's in what result row there is an ID of 1) and nothing else.

I've Google'd as much as I could with varying results... either having really slow queries for larger tables or having to create all sorts of temporary tables and user variables (the former I'd REALLY like to avoid, the latter I suppose I can live with).

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [artfulsoftware](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#460):

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.name, COUNT( p2.name ) AS Rank
    FROM people p1
    JOIN people p2 
    ON p1.name < p2.name
    OR (
         p1.name = p2.name
         AND p1.id = p2.id
    )
GROUP BY p1.id, p1.name
ORDER BY p1.name DESC , p1.id DESC
LIMIT 4,1
```

Comment: After a few small changes this does seem to work pretty darn well for what I need. However, one additional complication: would it be possible to select a set of rows given a set of conditions (such as, only people that have a 'J' in their name -- WHERE name LIKE '%j%'. I tried this, and while the result field 'rank' is still relevant, it skips numbers for those that don't have a J in the name. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
SELECT Row, id, name
FROM (SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS Row, id, name
      FROM people
      ORDER BY name ASC)
WHERE Row = @SomeRowNumber
```

If you want to go by the ID, just alter the where clause.

Comment: Its giving error that Every derived table must have its own alias @Brandon

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, p.id, p.name
FROM people p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: This is like what I had previously come up with Googling, and it works great if I want the 'rank' of every row within my table, but what if I want only the rank of a single row?

I tried something like

<pre>
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 `rank`, p.id, p.name
FROM people p, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
WHERE id = 5
ORDER BY name ASC
</pre>

But this will always give me a rank of 1 (because it only ever returns one result). Is there a way to get the single rank of a single row based on the entire query results?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: how to get just one record with that particular rank using your query @Plutor

Answer (score 0):

I try to this code... may help other
I am getting result from users and upload table for user profile pic and join it than after i am calculating user points and sorting on them.
At last am checking and adding row number for ranking for users...
Injoy it.
thanks

```
set @row_num = 0;
set @calp =0;
select  if(@calp=(@calp:=user.cal_points), @row_num, @row_num := @row_num + 1) as row_number,user.* from 
(select user_skills.*,users.username,upload.file_name from user_skills join users on user_skills.user_id=users.id join upload on upload.upload_id=users.profile_pic order by user_skills.cal_points desc) as user
WHERE user.skill_name LIKE  '%ph%'
```