# SQL php recordset position

Tags: php, sql

All the players in my php game are stored in a table named `players`, in that table it has the fields `id`, `name` and `score`.

Say I was on a players profile page, i want to know how to get his score position out of all the game players. So if he had the highest score in the whole table, his Position would be #1.

How would I write the query for that?

Comment: I would take a look at the accepted answer from this SO question: [Using MySQL, how do I select query result rank of one particular row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262448/using-mysql-how-do-i-select-query-result-rank-of-one-particular-row)

Comment: How do you want to handle `players` who are tied for `score`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT COUNT(id)+1 AS rank FROM players WHERE score>[yourPlayerScore]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this out? :

```sql
SET @rank=0;
SELECT rank 
FROM (
    SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, name, score
    FROM players
    ORDER BY score DESC
) ranks 
WHERE id = <id of person whose profile is showing>;
```